# False rejection control techniques review

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

As far as I know, in multiple hypothesis testing scenarios there are methods to control for the False Discovery Rate (FDR) and the Family-Wise Error Rate (FWER) but I'm not aware of any method for controlling the [type 2 error $\beta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors), that is the probability of not rejecting false null hypotheses.

Does any such method exists? If so, can you please point me to the literature? If not, what is the main limitation for these approaches to exist?

Comment: Give a definition of FRR? Or a cite?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: *Not*  being rejected? Then why call it a "rejection rate"? In any event, maybe you are looking for notions of power. Like with the type I error rates, there are many notions of power for multiple testing that have been developed, named, studied, and hard coded into available software.

Comment: Thanks for the referral to power but I meant something different therefore I re-edited my question. To put it in other words, I'm not aware of any method that bounds the probability of not rejecting the null hypothesis when the alternative hypothesis is true. Sorry for making a bit of confusion but I'm not very into the topic therefore it's easy for me to make mistakes when asking things/trying to explain myself